# Proof the Fibonacci numbers are not a polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I was asked a while ago to prove there is no polynomial $P$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $P(i)=f_i$ for all $i\geq0$. I tried to get a proof as slick as possible and here's what I got.

Let $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_1x+a_0$ . Construct the polynomials $p_1(x)=a_n(x-1)^n+a_{n-1}(x-1)^{n-1}+\dots +a_1(x-1)+a_0$ and $p_2(x)=a_n(x-2)^n+a_{n-1}(x-2)^{n-1}+\dots +a_1(x-2)+a_0$.

Then the polynomial $p-(p_1+p_2)$ has infinitely many roots since $p(i)=p_1(i)+p_2(i)$ for $i$ an integer $\ge 1$ because of the Fibonacci recurrence. Hence we have $p_1+p_2=p$ since a  non-zero polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ zeros.

However $p_1+p_2$ has leading coefficient $2a_n$. So they cannot be equal.

What do you think of my proof. Can you find other proofs? Simpler proofs? harder proofs? The less standard the better. I appreciate proofs which might look excessive in the amount of theory they use, although only if they finish quickly.

Thank you very much.

Regards

Comment: Except for slight nits on the notation used, looks good. You may want to use plus signs to seperate the terms and use $p_1(x), p_2(x)$ to avoid confusion with derivatives.

Comment: thanks, I think It's better now.

Comment: The change in notation cleared up your argument for me. Very nice and simple. I guess my experience as an analyst lead me in a different direction.

Comment: Fibonacci numbers grow faster than any polynomial, so just start with some asymptotic formula.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

(A riff on a deleted answer:)

Any polynomial sequence has a rational generating function of the form $\frac{P(x)}{(1-x)^k}$. This can be seen by repeatedly differentiating the geometric series.

The Fibonacci sequence has generating function $\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$, which is not of this form. Since generating functions are unique, it follows that the Fibonacci sequence is non-polynomial.

Comment: You math guys never cease to amaze me. (I'm a physics guy who programs games)

Comment: @Micah I often heard about generating functions of sequences here on math.SE, but I've never had it covered by the lectures I attended so far and I'd like to learn about them. Can you tell me what keywords I have to look for / in what branch of maths this concept is used?

Comment: @flawr I recommend Graham, Knuth, Patashnik 'Concrete Mathematics. A Foundation for Computer Science'. Generating functions are pretty well covered there and book doesn't require much mathematical knowledge.

Comment: @flawr Generating functions are a standard topic covered in a combinatorics course. They are also used in number theory. When I was an undergraduate I read "A Walk through Combinatorics" by Miclos Bona. He has a couple of good chapters on the subject in there.

Comment: @flawr: I learned about generating functions from Herbert Wilf's *generatingfunctionology*. An older edition of it is [freely and legally available as a pdf](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for those recommendations (and sorry for hijacking the comments =) PS: Do we have a collection of freely available math books somewhere?

Answer (score 47):

Taking successive differences of a nonzero polynomial should result in a polynomial of the next smallest degree. That is, if $p$ is degree $n$, then $p(x)-p(x-1)$ should be of degree $n-1$.

But if $p(i)$ gives Fibonacci numbers, then $p(i)-p(i-1)=p(i-2)$. So $\deg p=\deg(p)-1$, a contradiction. (This is a different take on your argument (which is great) since you asked about alternatives.)

Comment: I like it. Although the degree is at most $n-1$ I think. (It doesn't matter for the solution though).

Comment: What I meant is that in the first paragraph it whould say " That is, if $p$ is degree $n$ then $p(x)-p(x-1)$ should be degree at most $n-1$"

Comment: @ModdedBear While with arbitrary polynomials you have to worry about cancellation, here in fact the result is sharp; $p(x)-p(x-1)$ will be of degree _exactly_ $n-1$.  (This can be shown via a discrete version of the FTC; if you're curious about the details I encourage you to ask a question about it.)

Comment: Oh yeah. The proof is simple. The coeficient of the leading term is going to be $-na_n$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: What is "here" -- i.e. which properties of $p$ is it that guarantees the sharp result? Since we're concluding that $p$ doesn't exist at all, everything holds about it vacuously, but is there anything in particular you had in mind?

Comment: @HenningMakholm That it's a polynomial.  For any polynomial of degree $n$, the polynomial $p(t)-p(t-1)$ will always be of degree exactly $n-1$; there are no possible cancellations that can make it of lower degree (which is not the case when subtracting arbitrary polynomials of degree $n$, of course).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Ah, okay. I thought that you said that if $p$ is an arbitrary polynomial then you'd need to worry about cancellation in $p(x)-p(x-1)$, but not for the particular one we were looking at here.

Comment: Yeah, I had got that too at first :)

Answer (score 26):

If we consider ratios of the Fibonacci numbers we can come up with a quick growth rate: $$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n}} = \frac{F_{n} + F_{n-1}}{F_n} = 1 + \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}<2$$ and $$\frac{F_{n-1}}{F_{n}} = \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}} > \frac{F_{n-1}}{2 F_{n-1}} = 1/2$$ which means $$1.5 < \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} < 2.$$ Hence, $(1.5)^n < F_n < 2^n$ for $n>1$ which means that the growth rate for the Fibonacci numbers is exponential.

Suppose $p(i)=F_i$ for some polynomial (of degree $m$) then the polynomial can be written as $$p(x) = a_m x^m + a_{m-1} x^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0.$$ Thus $$|F_n| = |p(n)| \le n^m \sum_{i=1}^m |a_m| := Cn^m.$$ This means $$(1.5)^n < Cn^m$$ for all $n$.

We can demonstrate that this inequality cannot hold for all $n$. It is clearer when logarithms are used: $$(1.5)^n < Cn^m$$ which means $$n \ln(1.5) < \ln(C) + m \ln(n)$$ and $$\ln(1.5) < \frac{\ln(C)}{n} + m \frac{\ln(n)}{n}.$$ The term $\ln(C)/n$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ and so does $\ln(n)/n$. However, since $\ln(1.5) > 0$ this is a contradiction.

Comment: I've seen that argument , I like it. can you make the part in the end actually do the math though? thanks.

Comment: Which part would you like me to clarify? The polynomial growth or the exponential inequality?

Comment: The part at the very end where you say polynomial growth is slower than exponential growth. Everything else is perfect.

Comment: Changed as requested. :)

Answer (score 8):

Consider repeated differences. That is,  write down a row $p(1),p(2),p(3),\ldots$ and then in the next row the differences $p(2)-p(1),p(3)-p(2),p(4)-p(3),\ldots$ of the first row, then in the third row the differences of the second row, and so on. It should be well-known that a row obtained from a polynomial of degree $n$ produces values from a polynomial of degree $n-1$ in the next row and so on, so eventually we arrive at a degree $0$ (i.e., constant) row and from than on at all-zero rows.

However, if we start this with the Fibonacchi sequence, the next row is the (shifted) Fibonacci sequence and we will never obtain an all-zero row.

Comment: Actually, this proof might be viewed just as a disguise of your own proof

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was thinking with my answer. I'm at a loss as to why my answer here took off so much, but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 2):

$F_1=1$ and $F_3=2$ so their difference is odd.

Polynomials have the property $P(x+n)-P(x)$ is divisible by $n$, and in particular $P(x+2)-P(x)$ is always even.

Comment: Interesting... but, does this disprove polynomials with noninteger coefficients?

Comment: Perhaps not ...

Comment: @orion If it's a polynomial, we may assume that it's a polynomial with rational coefficients (with denominators dividing the factorial of the degree).  So $cF_n =p(n)$ for some polynomial with integer coefficients, $c$ an integer.  Then for $(n,c)=1$, we need $n \mid F_{x+n}-F_x$ for all $x$.  Can we do anything with this?

Comment: @A Walker: Perhaps not: $n(n+1)/2$ is an example of a polynomial with rational coefficients where $P(x+2)-P(x)$ is odd

Answer (score 2):

The simplest I can think of, in broad strokes: Fibonacci numbers are roughly exponential, and an exponential function grows faster than any polynomial, so they can't be represented by a polynomial.  QED.

We can formalize this to pretty much any level desired.  Let's start with the first assertion, that Fibonacci numbers are roughly exponential.  Fibonacci numbers are defined by F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2), plus some initial conditions (here, F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, but similar sequences with different initial conditions work just as well).  Dividing through (since F(n) is positive for n > 0, we'll assume an appropriate n), F(n)/F(n - 1) = 1 + F(n - 2)/F(n - 1), so if we define r(n) = F(n)/F(n - 1), r(n) = 1 + 1/r(n - 1).  Let r(k) = ø + e for some e and k.  Then r(k + 1) = 1 + 1/(ø + e).  1/(ø + e) = (1/ø)/(1 + e/ø), which, when |e/ø| < 1, is a geometric series, (1/ø)(1 - e/ø + (e/ø)^2 - ...).  Going back to r(k + 1), that's 1 + (1/ø)(1 - e/ø + ...) = 1 + 1/ø - (e/ø^2)(1 - e/ø + ...) = 1 + 1/ø - (e/ø^2)/(1 + ø/e) = 1 + 1/ø - (e/ø)(1/(ø + e)).  Now, ø = (1 + sqrt(5))/2, so 1 + 1/ø = ø.  Therefore, r(k + 1) = ø - (e/ø)(1/(ø + e), or, in other words, r(k + 1) = ø + f, where f = -(e/ø)(1/(ø + e)).  For all e < -ø^3 or e > -ø, |f| < |e|, though we must make sure that -ø < e < ø for the geometric series trickery to work, and for the Fibonacci sequence in particular, the first real value for r is r(2) = 1, with e = ø - 1 falling well in this range and, subsequent differences being smaller, only produces more values in this range.  Therefore, we can say that growth of the Fibonacci series is bounded between r(n) = 1 and r(n) = 2ø - 1.  However, the sequence being bounded by 1^n isn't particularly useful, so we'll use the next two ratios of 2 and 3/2 to note that Cl·(3/2)^n ≤ F(n) ≤ Cr·2^n, where Cl and Cr are positive constants.  In particular, F(n) ≥ Cl·(3/2)^n.

The rest can be proved similarly, in as much detail as you care about.